# What are the parameters of the sub-exponential distribution that is sub-Gaussian squared?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I understand that the square of a sub-Gaussian is sub-exponential (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.3027.pdf, Lemma 5.14) but it's not clear to me as to what the parameters of the sub-exponential are, given that the sub-Gaussian has parameter $\sigma$.

I know that a Gaussian with parameter $\sigma$ when squared yields a sub-exponential with parameters $(2\sigma^2,4\sigma^2)$, would the same apply to a sub-Gaussian too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, this paper shows that the parameters of the sub-exponential are $(4\sqrt{2} \sigma^2, 4 \sigma^2)$
 http://proceedings.mlr.press/v33/honorio14-supp.pdf
(although I do not have a tighter characterization of the parameters).

Comment: It actually depends on the definition. You get a very neat and elegant conncetion between sub-exponential and sub-gaussian random variables if you choose a more restrictive definition of sub-exponential notion as they did in https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf in Section 2.7 and 2.8. Roughly speaking this is the same as you definition but it restricts both paramters to be equal up to an absolute constant.